# PHP. В чем преимущества и недостатки вывода переменных первого способа перед вторым и наоборот

Tags: php, переменные, вывод

Я вижу только то, что в первый способ короче и проще, недостатков не увидел. Второй способ мне кажется менее удобным из-за конкатенации. Однако выводят же переменные и через первый способ, и через второй. И какой способ более предпочтительный на ваш взгляд?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Первый сайт на PHP</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $a1 = 1.5; 
        $a2 = 20;
        echo "a1 = $a1, a2 = $a2 <br>"; // 1-й способ
        echo "a1 = " . $a1 . ", a2 = " . $a2; // 2-й способ
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Используйте первый способ. Он быстрее в PHP 7 http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/156712d39a8dc8868b7e540424b2890a0ecf5273

Answer (score 0):

Ликбезы по этому поводу, идут уже лет 5 как, на самом деле все упирается в скорость, и вы чаще встретите конструкцию где используется конкатенация:

```
echo $a . ' t = ' . $t;
```

Чем конструкцию вывода с помощью шаблонов или вывода в строках:

```
echo "t = {$t}";// через шаблоны
echo "t = $t";
```

Можете также посмотреть код популярных фреймворков, там также чаще используется конкатенация, **но** если ваш проект не упирается в супер скорость, вы можете использовать шаблоны, ибо это гораздо более понятный способ соответственно код выглядит куда приятнее. Печален тот факт что нет никаких рекомендаций со стороны `php-fig` по поводу вывода данных в строках.